# Change onclick function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Change onclick function using javascript ?

for example

normally checkbox is `onclick="fn()"`

after `alert(TEST);` i want to change from `onclick="fn()"` to `onclick="return false;"`

How can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/8xhc5p4n/2/

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#check_box").change(function fn() {        
        alert("TEST");
        // change from `onclick="fn()"` to `onclick="return false;"`
    });
});
```

Comment: SOunds like http://api.jquery.com/one/ is what you should be using and not using an inline event?

Answer (score 3):

Better way:

```
var check = true;
function fn(){
   if(check)
     {
        alert(...);
        check = false;
     }
   else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#check_box").change(function fn() {        
            alert("TEST");
            $("#check_box").attr("onclick","return false;");
            //change from `onclick="fn()"` to `onclick="return false;"`
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#check_box").change(function fn() {        
        alert("TEST");
        //change from `onclick="fn()"` to `onclick="return false;"`
        this.setAttribute("onclick","return false;");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved in two ways, if you are using jQuery

```
$('#check_box').on('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('onclick', 'return false;');
})
```

or if you want to use vanilla / EcmaScript 5

```
document.querySelector("#check_box").addEventListener('click', (function(){
    this.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false;');
})();)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuerys [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) a [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) functions

http://jsfiddle.net/8tq300mk/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have already answered your own question.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check_box" name="check_box" value="Shared" onclick="return false">
```

is completely valid code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).attr('onclick', 'return false;');` as shown below:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#check_box").change(function() {        
        $(this).attr('onclick', 'return false;');
    });
});
```

Here's an updated version of your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xhc5p4n/5/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#check_box").change(function fn() {        
        alert("TEST");

        $("#check_box").click(function() {
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.